How to Properly Case Change in ToC Entries and Make Chapter Numbers Clickable
I'm facing two issues with my LaTeX document's Table of Contents (ToC):

Formatting Issue with \capitalisewords:

I am using the \titlecontents command to format my ToC.
I want to capitalize the words in the ToC using \capitalisewords from the mfirstuc package.
However, \capitalisewords does not seem to work as expected. The ToC entries remain unchanged.
Interestingly, if I use other case-changing commands like \MakeLowercase, they work perfectly.


Clickable and Colored \thecontentslabel:

Before manually formatting the ToC entries using \titlecontents, the ToC lines were fully clickable and colored, thanks to the hyperref package.
After using \titlecontents, the chapter numbers (\thecontentslabel) are no longer clickable or colored, although the rest of the entry is.



Here's a minimal working example (MWE) that demonstrates these issues:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum, mfirstuc, titletoc}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true]{hyperref}

\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\addvspace{.5em}}% <above-code>
  {\thecontentslabel\quad\capitalisewords}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {\capitalisewords}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
  []%

\titlecontents{section}[3.8em]{}{\contentslabel{2.3em}\capitalisewords}{\hspace*{-2.3em}\capitalisewords}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[7em]{}{\contentslabel{3.2em}\capitalisewords}{\hspace*{-3.2em}\capitalisewords}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{starred chapter title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{starred chapter title}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{chapter title}
\lipsum[2]

\section{section title}
\lipsum[3]

\subsection{subsection title}
\lipsum[3-18]

\end{document}

Here is the resulting ToC:

My questions are:

How can I get \capitalisewords to work correctly with \titlecontents?
How can I make \thecontentslabel clickable and colored again, like the rest of the ToC entry?

Any suggestions or solutions?

It is better to ask only one question per question.

I completely agree with you that it's generally best to focus on one issue per post. but, in this case, I suspected that the color and clickability issues might be linked to my main problem, so I decided to cover them together in a single question. @UlrikeFischer
